# Mov video not playing in web but playing in VLC Media Player

Tags: video, quicktime, mov

I have a problem with my Mov video, Its playing well in the my desktop player like VLC but when I embedded it to my website, it's not playing. [Checkout the test page](http://goscrub.com/sample-page/) and Here's the code.

**Use this code in the** `<head>` **of your web page:**

```
<script src="http://www.apple.com/library/quicktime/scripts/ac_quicktime.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.apple.com/library/quicktime/scripts/qtp_library.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://www.apple.com/library/quicktime/stylesheets/qtp_library.css" rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Use this code in the** `<body>` **of your web page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    QT_WritePoster_XHTML('Click to Play', 'GoScRUB_Infomercial-poster.jpg',
        'GoScRUB_Infomercial.mov',
        '853', '496', '',
        'controller', 'true',
        'autoplay', 'true',
        'bgcolor', 'black',
        'scale', 'aspect');
//-->
</script>
<noscript>
<object width="853" height="496" classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
    <param name="src" value="GoScRUB_Infomercial-poster.jpg" />
    <param name="href" value="GoScRUB_Infomercial.mov" />
    <param name="target" value="myself" />
    <param name="controller" value="false" />
    <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
    <param name="scale" value="aspect" />
    <embed width="853" height="496" type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"
        src="GoScRUB_Infomercial-poster.jpg"
        href="GoScRUB_Infomercial.mov"
        target="myself"
        controller="false"
        autoplay="false"
        scale="aspect">
    </embed>
</object>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I hope this'll help you

```
<div class="embeddedVideo">
    <object classid='clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B'
        width="600" height="400"
        codebase='http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab'>
        <param name='src' value="assets/videos/movie.mov">
        <param name='autoplay' value="false">
        <param name='controller' value="true">
        <param name='loop' value="false">

        <embed src="assets/videos/movie.mov" width="600" height="400"
        scale="tofit" autoplay="false"
        controller="true" loop="false" bgcolor="#000000"
        pluginspage='http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/'>
        </embed>
    </object>     
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I already switched to HTML5 before your answer, but this is working.